# Putting a child in "time out" en Español

Tags: traducción

Is there a proper way to say "time out" in Spanish? I've just been using the English word with my son, which he understands, but I'd like something en Español, if something other than a literal translation could be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know what's most used while talking about the technique is the literal translation "Tiempo fuera" but talking to the child, specially if they're very youg "ir al rincón/a la silla de pensar" or whatever place you use fo your kid times out.

Comment: Nunca he oído "tiempo fuera", en España, refiriéndose a castigar a alguien.

Comment: @Telaclavo no habrás visto muchos capítulos de Súper nanny :D

Comment: No, he visto uno o dos capítulos (no me gustan). Esa nanny no ha aprendido eso aquí, en España. Lo ha importado. Busca en la RAE, en las entradas "tiempo" y "fuera", y no verás absolutamente nada referente a ese significado. Me sorprende que alguien haya votado "up" esta respuesta. No sé en otros países, pero desde luego, en España, nada más lejos de la realidad.

Comment: @Telaclavo la RAE no es diós y por eso en la respuesta he especificado la diferencia entre la técnica (muy utilizada entre los padres hoy en día) y como se expresa a los niños, me parece muy osado decir que "en España nada más lejos de la realidad" cuando tanto padres como educadores han adoptado el rincón o silla de pensar y es una expresión utilizada habitualmente.

Comment: La RAE no es dios, pero de esto saben más que tú y yo, "dios" no se acentúa, y "tiempo fuera" NO es una expresión utilizada habitualmente en España. He vivido en 5 sitios de este país. Desde luego, que en tu respuesta no menciones la expresión "estás castigado" (que es lo que dice el 99.9% de la población) me parece no ya osado, sino infiel a la realidad.

Comment: @Telaclavo verás es que la pregunta no es como se dice "you are grounded" sinó la expresión específica para la técnica del "time out" que es un tipo concreto de castigo con toda una teoría psicológica detrás de la que te he puesto un enlace en tu respuesta. Y no pretendo saber más que los académicos pero muchísimas expresiones habituales no están en el diccionario de la RAE.

Comment: Por mi parte, no voy a usar "tiempo fuera" porque me parece un mal ejemplo de traducir un frase de inglés a español. Me gustó la respuesta porque me ofrece otro ejemplo como hablar con mi hijo. También me gustó su ejemplo @teclavo porque me da más entendiemiento sobre el uso de palabras en otro partes del mundo, aunque "castigado" me parece muy duro por un hijo de 17 meses.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque no especifiquen que van a tener que permanecer castigados en un sitio concreto, yo diría que las más utilizadas, en el castellano de España, son: "Estás castigado", o simplemente "¡castigado!", o "castigado contra la pared" (en las aulas de clase. Esta sí especifica el lugar) o "¡castigado! ¡A tu habitación!" (también lo especifica).

La expresión "tiempo fuera" no se la he oído a nadie que haya crecido en España. Mirad estos enlaces:
http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=tiempo
http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=fuera

No encontraréis en ellos ninguna referencia a "tiempo fuera", ni a castigar.

En España, la expresión es "estás castigado" (seguida o no de si especificamos dónde tiene que cumplir el castigo).

Comment: http://www.apasanantonio.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=334:tecnica-del-rincon-de-pensar&catid=67:educacion&Itemid=89